# How to check if property exist before retrieving it using SpListItem.Item

Tags: api, sharepoint

I need to get the value of an SplistItem.Item. There is a new property that was added "ShortenedUrl". The problem is that, old pages does not contain this property so I get an error of "Value does not fall within the expected range" whenever the site is an old page.

Is there a way to check first if the item exist?
before getting the value?

Here's is my code.

```
        'Set shortened URL
        Dim objShortUrl As Object = postItemById.Item("ows_ShortenedUrl")
        If objShortUrl IsNot Nothing Then
            blogPost.shortURL = objShortUrl
        Else
            blogPost.shortURL = DBNull.Value
        End If
```

What can I do to check first if "ows_ShortenedUrl" exist?

Answer (score 5):

SPFieldCollection.ContainsField just checks the schema. You can have a field defined in a schema, and the value can still be null.  If you know it's in the schema, just check item[fieldName] == null.

```
if (item.Fields.ContainsField(fieldName) && item[fieldName] != null) {

   //do something with it

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Item.Fields.ContainsField to check.